# need to load table data to xml file in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

Now am using this command to load table data to XML file in MySQL

```
mysql --user=username--password=pwd test123 --xml 'select * from TableName' > XmlFileName.xml
```

It is generating xml file in below format

```
<row>
  <column1>value1</column1>
  <column2>value2</column2>
</row>
```

but i want to generate XML file like below:

```
<row>
  <field name='column1'>value1</field>
  <field name='column2'>value2</field>
</row>
```

You can refer this link (I need to generate xml in third format)
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/load-xml.html

Comment: `"load table data _to_ XML file"` The documentation you gave concerns loading data _from_ an XML file _into_ a table.  MySQL recognizes three formats, so this is not chosen by you.

Comment: sorry,    for Format purpus ,I mentioned  that documentation

Comment: sorry,    to refer  Format ,I mentioned  that documentation URL  and I need to generate XML file in third format (can see that format using that URL)....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need mysqldump, try:

```
mysqldump --xml --user=username --password=pwd test123 TableName
```

Comment: even posted command also working,Now XML file is generating in first format but i need to generate XML file in third format you can see this format in this URL :docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/load-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with command you pasted in your question.

- You need the `-e` flag
- The database name should be included in the query like `database.table`
- you are missing a space between `username` and `--password` flag

It should look like this:

```
mysql --user=username --password=pwd --xml -e 'SELECT * FROM DbName.TableName' > XmlFileName.xml
```

This should give the desired output, as will the other answer posted here by Rodney Salcedo which uses `mysqldump`.

Comment: mysql --user=root --password=root --xml -e "select *
 from test123.Table-name" >file.xml                                        //  I used this command   generating xml file in another format but I need to generate in                                                                         <row>
  <field name='column1'>value1</field>
  <field name='column2'>value2</field>
</row>

Comment: even posted command also working,Now XML file is generating in first format but i need to generate XML file in third format you can see this format in this URL :docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/load-xml.html

Comment: For me it does generate third format.  Maybe a difference with the MySQL version you are using.  Have you tried Rodney's answer using `mysqldump`?  It also should give the desired output.

Comment: Am using MySQL 5.5 ,may be it's not supported for third format...Please tell me which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: MySQL 5.5.46 / ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

To export data as xml, try:

```
mysql -uroot -p --xml -e "SELECT * FROM table_name" > table_name.xml
```

To import xml data, try:

```
LOAD XML table_name.xml INTO TABLE table_name;
```

Have a look into tools like **workbench** that could help you export the data obtained after executing the particular query. I recently had a look into **sqlyog** that sports the same feature, the difference is the latter has a good GUI.

Comment: command is working ,Now XML file is generating in first format but i need to generate XML file in third format you can see this format in this URL :https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/load-xml.html

Comment: The command does generate the output in the third format to me.

Comment: Am using MySQL 5.5 ,may be it's not supported for third format...Please tell me which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: Which Operating System you are using?